# Search bar not displaying results in React

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching the data of all products from an API call. All these products are objects. I am then checking if the value of search sting is present in all the productsindividually. If yes, that product is added to a different array. All the elements'titles in this different array are displayed as a dropdown menu.
Where am I going wrong? Plz help

**Code on React:**

```
import Head from "next/head";
const App = () => {
  var resultfoundarray=[];
  const [Searchquery,setSearchquery] = useState("");
  const [AllProducts,setAllProducts] = useState([]);
  
  
    const allproducts = () =>{
      fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
              .then(res=>res.json())
              .then(json=>{console.log(json);
                setAllProducts(json);
                console.log(AllProducts);
              })
    } 

  const search = () =>{
    allproducts();
    AllProducts.forEach(prod => {
      if(Searchquery in prod){
        resultfoundarray.push(prod.title);
      }
    });
  }
    return(
          <> 
          <StrictMode>
         <Head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/general.css"></link>
         </Head>
          <div>
          <div className="searchbardiv">
            <div>
       

 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={e=>setSearchquery(e.target.value) ></input>
            <span><button type="submit" onClick={ e => search()}>Search</button></span>
            <div>
              <select>
                {resultfoundarray.map((prodtitle) => {
                  <option>
                    {prodtitle}
                  </option>
                })}  
          </div>
        </div>
        </StrictMode>
          </>
        )
        }
    export default App;
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what the `prod` object and `Searchquery` look like?

Comment: **prod object:   
{
  id:1,
  title:'...',
  price:'...',
  category:'...',
  description:'...',
  image:'...'
}**
(The response is a list of similar objects)                                                                                     
Searchquery is the input in the search bar:
**eg: silver**

Comment: Are you searching by the object property name or product title in the search bar?

Comment: Product title. I am checking the string in search bar with product title

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the fetch is running in the background, updating `AllProducts` asynchronously.  In your `search` function, you trigger the fetch and access `AllProducts` immediately after *starting* the fetch, *before* the results came back.

You should trigger the fetch when the component mounts:

```js
useEffect(() => allProducts(), []);
```

And then react to state changes in `AllProducts`

```js
useEffect(() => AllProducts?.forEach(prod => {
  if (Searchquery in prod) {
    resultfoundarray.push(prod.title);
  }
}, [AllProducts]);
```

There are more minor issues (e.g. it would be better to use `useState` for managing `resultfoundarray` too), but I guess you'll figure that out.

The full code would look like this (just copied & pasted, there is no guarantee it works):

```js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  var resultfoundarray = [];
  const [Searchquery, setSearchquery] = useState("");
  const [AllProducts, setAllProducts] = useState([]);

  const allproducts = () => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setAllProducts(json);
        console.log(AllProducts);
      });
  };

  // load all products when component mounts
  useEffect(() => allproducts(), []);

  // update results found after products are loaded 
  // or the when search query changes
  useEffect(
    () =>
      AllProducts?.forEach((prod) => {
        if (Searchquery in prod) {
          resultfoundarray.push(prod.title);
        }
      }),
    [AllProducts, SearchQuery]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <StrictMode>
        <Head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/general.css"></link>
        </Head>
        <div className="searchbardiv">
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search"
              onChange={(e) => setSearchquery(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <span>
              <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => search()}>
                Search
              </button>
            </span>
            <div>
              <select>
                {resultfoundarray.map((prodtitle) => {
                  <option>{prodtitle}</option>;
                })}{" "}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </StrictMode>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I understand your point. But even if runs asynchronously AllProducts[] is being displayed in console log. So whenever it is displayed it should display the products right? But instead it comes as an empty array. What is the reason for AllProducts being an empty array in console log? Because it will be displayed in console log only after the allproducts() is executed fully right?

Comment: This is because setAllProducts does not update the state immediately. console.log(AllProducts) will print the old value, even if called directly after setAllProducts. You can log the current state like this: useEffect(() => console.log(AllProducts), [AllProducts]);

Comment: Ok got it. Could u post the entire code with the edited part included? Because when I am adding the useEffect() , I am getting error "cant use hook inside functions"

Comment: I updated the answer and pasted my code fragments where they would need go in the original code. Unfortunately, the original code doesn't compile, so I am not sure if it works out of the box

Answer (score 0):

There are issues as others have pointed out. But the issue you are not seeing any result being displayed is because of this condition

`if(Searchquery in prod){`

You are searching by the product property name instead of the product title. To correct that, the condition should be

`if (prod.title.includes(Searchquery ))`